# jquery if error message displayed, keep current state

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a form that displays the user's current account info and a click to edit button. When the user clicks the button, the hidden form fades in and become editable. The problem I'm having is that when an incorrect password is entered, the error messaging sends the form back to the original non-editable form. Is there a way to keep the user on the editable form (not toggle back)?.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#show_accountEdit').click(function() {
        $('#edit_account_details').fadeIn('slow', function () {});
        $('div.showhide, #NonEdit_account_details').toggle();
    });
    $('#cancel_accountEdit').click(function() {
        $('#NonEdit_account_details').fadeIn('slow', function () {});
        $('div.showhide,#edit_account_details').toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: So you send the form to a the server and process it server side, but direct the user back when there is an error in the form data. Is that correct? And welcome to SO!

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The error displays client side when there's a mismatch server side. Thanks for the welcome!

Comment: Can we see your form submission code?

Comment: Here's the code and screenshots. Not worried about form validating error messages, just want to edit js code in snippet so form stays on screenshot 2 instead of toggling back to screenshot 1.

[Code](https://snipt.net/gunjack/js-form-error/)

[Screen 1](http://cl.ly/image/2D2q323Q470F)

[Screen 2](http://cl.ly/image/2w3l2E18402a)

[Screen 3 - error messaging](http://cl.ly/image/0A313Q1m3N06)

Comment: Could we see the validation code too?